# insert into table(var1) select from itself

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into the last column (number of people in that room) and 
I want to use

```
insert into table(n_people_in_room) 
select count(people_id)
from table
group by room
```

This is obvious wrong because i need to join the table with itself on people_id but i didn't. What is the right code?

[image: INPUT]

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using an inline view to get the N_People_In_Room totals:

I'd do it as a SELECT first:

```
 SELECT t.peopleid
      , t.room
      , t.n_people_in_room AS `old_npir`
      , s.n_people_in_room AS `new_npir` 
  FROM mytable t
   JOIN ( SELECT c.room
               , COUNT(1) AS n_people_in_room
            FROM mytable c
           GROUP BY c.room
        ) s
     ON s.room = t.room
```

Convert that into an UPDATE by repacing `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE`, and adding a `SET` clause...

```
 UPDATE mytable t
   JOIN ( SELECT c.room
               , COUNT(1) AS n_people_in_room
            FROM mytable c
           GROUP BY c.room
        ) s
     ON s.room = t.room
    SET t.n_people_in_room = s.n_people_in_room
```